# Why does my jsp not display output?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

No errors at runtime and testing output to the console returns correct data but when I try to display same data in jsp nothing is displayed? Probably something really simple, I'm new to Spring and jsp.

Below are my jsp and DAO files:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
<%@page import="com.sga.app.dao.DisplayStatsDAO" %>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/css/main.css"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>SGA-user stats</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2 class="displayStatsLeaderboardHeader">Your stats</h2>
<table class="displayStatsTable" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td class="displayStatsTableData">${stats.returnForename()}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>


package com.sga.app.dao;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.sga.app.beans.UserBean;

@Component("displayStatsDAO")
@Transactional
@Repository
@Configuration
public class DisplayStatsDAO extends HttpServlet implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@Autowired
private LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory;

public void setLocalSessionFactoryBean(LocalSessionFactoryBean   sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public DisplayStatsDAO displayStatsDAO() {
    return new DisplayStatsDAO();
}

public DisplayStatsDAO() {

}

@Transactional
public String returnForename() {
    String returnValue = "";
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Session session =        sessionFactory.getConfiguration().buildSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication();
        String userLoggedIn = authentication.getName();
        System.out.println(userLoggedIn);
        session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(UserBean.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("username", userLoggedIn));
        List<UserBean> user = (List<UserBean>) criteria.list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        for (UserBean userDetails : user) {
            System.out.println("SHOW LOGGED-IN USER");
            System.out.println("Username: " + userDetails.getUsername());

            System.out.println("Name: " + userDetails.getForename() + ""
                    + userDetails.getSurname());
            returnValue = userDetails.getForename().toString();
            System.out.println(returnValue);
            return returnValue;
        }
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return returnValue;
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("userstats.jsp");
    req.setAttribute("stats", returnForename());        
    rd.forward(req, resp);
}
}
```

Edit: here are my controller/service classes

```
@Controller
public class DisplayStatsController {

   DisplayStatsService statsService;

   @Autowired
   public void setStatsService(DisplayStatsService statsService) {
        this.statsService = statsService;
        }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/userstats", method = RequestMethod.Get)
   public String showUserStatsPage(UserBean user, BindingResult, Model 
      model) {
         if (result.hasErrors()) {
               return "error";
            }
         else {
               try {
                    statsService.showUserStats();
                   }
               catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                      return "error";
                }
      }
}
 return "userstats";
}
```

And my service class:

```
@Service("displayStatsService")
public class DisplayStatsService {

private DisplayStatsDAO displayStatsDAO;

@Autowired
setDisplayStatsDAO(DisplayStatsDAO displayStatsDAO) {

   this.displayStatsDAO = displayStatsDAO;
}

   public void showUserStats() {
        displayStatsDAO.returnForename();
   }
}
```

log output:

```
DEBUG - Listing entities:
DEBUG - com.sga.app.beans.UserBean{surname=Bates,forename=John,gir=64, homeclub=Bearsden GC, email=john@bt.com, submitCount=18, }
DEBUG - committed JDBC Connection
DEBUG - re-enabling autocommit
SHOW LOGGED-IN USER
Username: John12345
Name: JohnBates
Homeclub: Bearsden GC
John12345
Bearsden GC
John
Outside try/catch clause
Return value is John
DEBUG - Flushing Hibernate Session on transaction synchronization
DEBUG - Processing flush-time cascades
DEBUG - Dirty checking collections
DEBUG - Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
DEBUG - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
DEBUG - Listing entities:
DEBUG - com.sga.app.beans.UserBean{surname=Bates, username=John12345,   forename=John,homeclub=Bearsden GC, email=john@bt.com}
DEBUG - Disconnecting session
DEBUG - Releasing JDBC connection
DEBUG - Released JDBC connection
DEBUG - HHH000163: Logical connection releasing its physical connection
DEBUG - Initiating transaction commit
DEBUG - Committing JDBC transaction on Connection 
DEBUG - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'userstats'
DEBUG - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'userstats'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsps/userstats.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
DEBUG - Added model object 'userBean' of type [com.sga.app.beans.UserBean] to request in view with name 'userstats'
DEBUG - Added model object 'org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.userBean' of type [org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult] to request in view with name 'userstats'
DEBUG - Added model object 'username' of type [java.lang.String] to request in view with name 'userstats'
DEBUG - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/jsps/userstats.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'userstats'
DEBUG - Successfully completed request
```

Comment: try with `<td class="displayStatsTableData">${stats}</td>`

Comment: @smoggers why did you return value in the for loop ?

Comment: Is there anything relevant in the log files?

Comment: @zawhtut so instead just set  returnValue rather than return it?    i.e returnValue = userDetails.getForename.toString();

Comment: @StephenC I added log output

Comment: I don't  really know what you are doing in there. Getting just one record from the list or you want a list of users whose forename is similar to logged in username. For the latter case, you have to use ArrayList or append to the string with commas.

Comment: I was originally returning an array of a user's details but that was returning null pointer exception in the jsp so changed the method to just return a string of just the logged-in user's forename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I got my jsp to output the data. I have a method in my Java class that retrieves the data I want and stores it within an Array then I set the HttpServletRequest attribute to this Array. In my jsp I refer to this Array and then output each element of the Array to table columns via a for loop.

```
<!-- Table -->
<table class="displayStatsTable" border="1">
    <tbody class="displayStatsTableBody">
        <tr class="displayStatsTableTopRow">
            <th><c:out value="Forename" /></th>
            <th><c:out value="Surname" /></th>
            <th><c:out value="Average Score" /></th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="stats" items="${stats}">
        <tr class="displayStatsTableDataRows">
            <td class="displayStatsTableData">${stats.forename}</td>
            <td class="displayStatsTableData">${stats.surname}</td>
            <td class="displayStatsTableData">${stats.score_avg}</td>
        </tr>           
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

With `req.setAttribute("stats", returnForename());` this line you are adding return value of function `returnForename()` in `stats` attribute, So on view you just have to access attribute `${stats}`.

Comment: Mark as answer, if correct and problem is solved. :)

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with your post but tried it and ultimately still nothing being displayed on jsp

Comment: Then where is your controller which will have an `RequestMapping` which calls your request and adds service return value to `model` attribute.

Comment: I added the controller/service classes

Answer (score 0):

I think you are highly confused right now.
In simple words Spring MVC works like-

> 1.you hit a URL,if that URL matches the RequestMapping present in the controller, execution is passed to that controller method.
>
> 2.That controller calls the service where logical code is present and it uses DAO layer.Service layer may return some data.
>
> 3.That data is saved is attributes and passed onto view(your jsp file).

What you are doing is calling the controller which call service which in turn DAO and DAO extends HttpServlet(completely wrong).

Either you use controller to call Dao or some class call that extends HttpServlet(again this doesn't come in spring), you can't use both.

Comment: ok so your saying move the DAO logic into the service in my case?

Comment: yes, since you are not using any database, all code should be only in controller and service. from controller return the name of the jsp file you want to call and the string you want to use in jsp must be set in model attribute for access  on jsp file

Comment: also get rid of the doGet method. it is not doing anything in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your jsp page, it will enable the EL and display the objects:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```